# Difference between the complex roots of $f(x)$ and $|f(x)|^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, computational-mathematics

I suppose a basic question, but it's causing me more problems than I envisioned!

I have some polynomial $f(x)$ for which the roots are complex, $x+iy$. How will these roots change if I now take $|f(x)|^2$?

In fact, I have a very large polynomial and I'm solving it numerically (on a computer, of course). However I need to check that the roots the computer is finding are genuine roots of $f(x)$ and I believe I can do this by plotting $|f(x)|^2$. However, I'm not sure what I should be expecting and looking for in this plot that confirms I have the proper root.

Answer (score 3):

I like to plot $1/|f(x)|$ instead of $|f(x)|$ if I'm trying to find the roots visually.  That way the roots of $f$ show up as poles in the plot.  They really stand out!

In Mathematica you could try something like

`Plot3D[1/Abs[f[x+I y]],{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5}]`

You can also use the options `PlotRange` and `PlotPoints` to tweak the output.  Here's an example:

`Plot3D[1/Abs[1+x+(x+I y)^2+3 (x+I y)^3+I y],{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3},PlotPoints->60,PlotRange->{0,4}]`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, $z=0$ iff $|z|=0$ iff $|z|^2=0$ for every complex number $z$, right?

Comment: So they're the same?

Comment: Actually, yes of course they are. But I still don't understand what's the benefit of me using $|f(x)|^2$ to check my roots? (I have been told I should do this)

Comment: @user13223423: I don't know your specific problem, but one reason might be that $|f(z)|$ can be visualized (as you said above) while $f(z)$ can't.

Also note that $|z|^2$ is $z\cdot\overline{z}$.  Maybe this is why they gave you this clue?

Comment: Yes I think you're right. I'm just unsure as to how plotting $|f(x)|^2$ is going to help me confirm I have the correct roots. If the roots are imaginary then I can never see them.

Comment: @user13223423: No, you're supposed to plot $|f(z)|$ as a function from $\mathbb{C}$ into the reals which will look like a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ into the reals, i.e. a 3D plot.  You'll see _all_ roots!

Comment: Oh that sounds promising, but I'm not too sure what you mean?

Comment: Tools like Mathematica or Maple should be able to do that without problems.  See for example [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/complexplot3d).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Is there an equivalent for Mathematica? I can't seem to find it on the documentation

Comment: Not to worry, think I've got it with ContourPlot. Hopefully I'll be able to see if I'm getting the correct roots now.